# Does the notion of a Poisson monad exist?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, poisson-geometry

Starting with a monoidal category with duals $C$, one may consider the category $End(C)$ of endofunctors of $C$. A Hopf monad on $C$ is a bimonad on $C$ with (a generalised notion of the)  antipode. Under suitable assumptions for the Hopf monad, this Hopf monad applied on the unit object of the category $C$ is a Hopf algebra in the centre of $C$.

The question is if the notion of Poisson monad in $End(C)$ has been defined somewhere? In the case that such a notion exists, does it return a Poisson algebra object in the category?

Comment: How does the monoidal structure with duals relate to your question?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The category of interest is monoidal with duals, and is essential for the Hopf monad case. Probably for the Poisson is not needed.

Comment: What is your reference for Hopf monads? You see,  there is a notion by [Mesablishvili & Wisbauer](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/10/26-10.pdf) which does not use any structure on the category except idempotent splitting, and there are others using monoidal structure essentially; if you mean the latter, there are several versions of these, which one do you mean? As for the Poisson structure, I believe you cannot formulate it without some form of *additivity* requirements, both on your category and on the endofunctor.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე My reference for Hopf monads is that of Brugieres-Virelizier.